# Firebase deploy - Not loading new page

Tags: firebase, polymer, polymer-1.0, firebase-hosting, progressive-web-apps

I am deploying a PWA to firebase using the tutorial from the polymer project website. I have no issues deploying to firebase, but if I deploy a second time the new page does not load. It will load the old page until I clear the cookies. I see understand that the way a PWA site works is like an application where it stores parts in memory for faster load times. Is there a setting I need to change to make it load most recently deployed webpage? I appreciate all the help, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be seeing an effect of your service worker. Try deleting the currently registered service worker from your browser so that the new one can take over.

In Chrome 51/52, open DevTools while on your site, and go to the **Resources** tab, and then **Service Workers** on the left panel. Click **Delete** to remove the service worker. You could also check the box for **Update on reload**, which allows you to update the service worker simply by refreshing the page.

[image]

Comment: So is there a time frame that the service worker will refresh on its own? I'm just wondering how other people will see changes to my site while not having to go into the dev tools and reload the service worker. Or is there a way to notify that a new version has been deployed and reload the service worker?